# C++ convert a reference to a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In the code below, `recordedModel()` returns a reference to `Model`. The function expects a pointer to be returned, is there a way in C++ to turn a reference into a pointer?

Comment: You get the address of the aliased object the same way you get the address of any other object, operator `&`.

Comment: `return &unit->recordedModel();`?

Comment: Do you know about the address-of operator `&`?

Comment: Note that references can never be addressed. Taking the address of a reference always gives you the address of the referred object.

Comment: `std::addressof` to be sure, as `mv::CompositionalModel` might have overloaded `operator &`.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way in C++ to turn a reference into a pointer?

Since references are not objects, they don't have an address, and there can not be a pointer to a reference.

However yes, you can get a pointer to the referred object. There is the address-of operator `&`, which returns the address of an object. The type of the address-value is pointer. The address-of operator is the inverse of the indirection operator `*` which takes a memory address (a pointer) as an operand and results in an lvalue object that is stored at the address. When applied to a reference, the address-of operator will return the address of the referred object.

Note that the address-of operator can be overloaded, so in generic code where you might not be aware of the overloads that the type has, if it is important to get the actual address of the object rather than something else that an overload might return, then the `std::addressof` function should be used instead of the address-of operator.